# Знаки препинания в поговорке

Tags: пунктуация

"Раз, два и обчелся" — как тут расставить знаки препинания? Во-первых, тире или запятая между "раз()два", во-вторых, требуется ли тире после "и"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Между "раз" и "два" - запятая, конечно, тире там ничем не мотивировано, а вот после "и" возможно тире. Хотя, думаю, необязательно. От интонации зависит, а она в поговорках обычно как раз такая, что тире просится. Посольку первая чать противопоставляется второй. 
Т.е. я бы писал "Раз, два - и обчелся".

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, "раз, два" через запятую, а перед "и" надо тире обязательно, согласно известному правилу, что между частями сложного предложения ставится тире при наличии быстрой смены событий или неожиданного присоединения